# Usage of verb "hang"

Tags: verbs, verb-forms

I'm reading a grammar book. The book has a section to determine the right subject and verb. In an example they use

> From the ceiling hung the chandelier.

Well, the verb is *hung*, and the subject is *chandelier*. But I'm a little bit confused about the usage of the verb *hung* in this sentence. Shouldn't it be

> The chandelier is hung from the ceiling.

From my Oxford dictionary, *hang* means *to suspend or be suspended from above with the lower part not attached*.

Obviously, the chandelier can't suspend itself. So there is a need to use the passive voice and omit the subject. In this case, the subject is not the chandelier, but the person who suspended. Or may be I'm missing something?

Comment: The chandelier most assuredly *can* "hang" all by itself. Or it could be "hung" by someone else. The only thing it can't be is "hanged" by someone else. That variation is only for executions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb *to hang* can be transitive or intransitive:

1. [Transitive] *We hung the pictures on the wall.*
2. [Intransitive] *The picture hangs in that room.*

Both are correct. See the [OALD's definition](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/hang) for further explanations.

Answer (score 0):

**From the ceiling hung the chandelier.** past tense

**From the ceiling hangs the chandelier.** present tense