# Use "hang" or "hung", when to use passive voice of "hang"?

Tags: passive-voice, participial-phrases, whiz-deletion

In this example, "framed picture hung on wall". "hang" is passive.

However, in "a picture of a dinosaur hanging on the wall ." and "many umbrellas hanging from the ceiling", "hang" is active.

I am confused. When to use "hang" and "hung"?

Comment: Don‘t forget capital crimes whose sentences pronounced by a judge once upon a time did come with wordings like *“shall **be hanged** from the neck until dead”* and such. That one is a “real” passive, but I don't think of yours as such. Native speakers don’t consciously think of every single past participle as being passive the way this question appears to, no more so than we think of every single present participle as being active, either—even though you **can** think of them that way, especially if you‘ve studied far too much Latin for your own good. :)

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42207/usage-of-verb-hang

Comment: _A picture hanging on the wall_ means it's still there, or was at image time. _A picture hung on the wall_ comments on the past installation of the picture, with no presumption about its present status or location; it got hung up, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're confusing the semantic classifier 'action verb' with the syntactic descriptors 'active' / 'passive' 'mood'.

To illustrate the moods:

- *I cooked the lamb.* [active mood]
- *The lamb was cooked by me.* [passive mood]
- *Lamb cooks best on a grille.* [middle usage – a typical middle usage having to do with permanent /durative properties of entities]

To address your question: Some would argue that 'A framed picture hung on the wall' is a middle mood usage.

To focus on 'action verbs':

*Kick, paint, cook, hang, push* ... are all action verbs, involving an action in their root sense (eg 'They hung the painting in the Louvre').

*Seem, want, need, belong [to]* ... are all non-action verbs.